# Word for "Shared but not exclusive"

Tags: single-word-requests

A word I know exists is escaping me right now and I'm hoping one of you can help. I'm looking for the word to replace X in the sentence:

"The skills of person A and those of person B are not X."

E.g person A has a lot of the same skills as person B but not completely the same. The items in group A and group B are not identical but they do share commonalities.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you thinking of *redundant*?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to fit **overlapping**, from [overlap](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/overlap#dataset-american-english), in your sentence by rephrasing it.

> If two or more things overlap, they have some parts or features that are the same.

Answer (score 0):

You could say

> The skills of person A and those of person B are not *identical*

or you could change it to a positive statement with *overlap* as in

> The skills of person A and those of person B *overlap*.

Per [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/overlap):

> to have parts that are the same as parts of something else

Answer (score 0):

Since you have given "The items in group A and group B are not identical but they do share commonalities.", I would say, the items are [similar](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/similar/%22similar%22). It basically means that the items have resemblances in nature or appearance.

Comment: The word in question is supposed to replace X in "The skills of person A and those of person B are not X." If you use "similar," you are saying they are not similar. Do you mean "not unsimilar"?

Comment: Ah! I just gave an explanation based on the example. I think it should be *dissimilar*.